# Java - Eclipse don't show stack and variables for errors

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I try to write some java in Eclipse.

When I put breakpoint. It's catched fine and dandy:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/00964b2f7c884277bd179074c12e9ad8.png

But after some error, there's no stack trace (and no variables to check).
There's only stack trace in console but not in "Debug" window.
http://image.prntscr.com/image/5df3b573e7314974b0d7577dfcdce727.png

UPDATE:

I tried to make error outside of TestingGEOJSONApp (in main) and it works fine.
So I guess its because of this "SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {"
http://image.prntscr.com/image/f03fea9847324dbbaf95b12517a393e7.png
Some global "catch" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But after some error, there's no stack trace (and no variables to check).

When Eclipse gets to know that an exception has been thrown *and not caught*, the full stack frames containing the values of the variables have been discarded by the JVM.  The stack frames are popped prior to catching the exception.  All that is left for Eclipse to show you is the stacktrace information.  That consists of just the class and method names and the line numbers.

To find out more information, you need to use Eclipse to set a breakpoint on the statement that actually throws the exception.

---

Note that this is not Eclipse's doing.  The exception stacktrace information is captured and managed  by the JVM.  The decision to only include class/method names and line numbers is baked into the Java runtime design and specifications.  (Capturing more information would make exception throwing slower, and there would be major concerns about security / privacy.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you now know that the line (in the picture you provided) causes an exception, place a break-point before that line to see the variables during execution. You even start "stepping" line by line to track the problem.